# Deploy specific folder in Github repository to AWS Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have a Github repository containing two folders, server and client. I want to deploy the server in AWS using CodePipeline and ElasticBeanstalk, but the source phase of the pipeline pulls both folders, which then gives an error during the deploy.

Is there a way to grab only the server folder?

Comment: Would a buildspec file help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CodePipeline GitHub source action will always "grab" the entire contents of the repo branch.  But the pipeline's build action can simply ignore the folders you don't need, operating only on your `server` folder.

Often this is as easy as adding `cd server` to the CodeBuild commands in the pipeline's [build action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html).